# How to call functions in composition react-hooks?

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, react-hooks, composition

I have one base hook(baseHook.js) which has some functions in it. Using composition I am trying to call those functions in child hook(formHook.js).

baseHook.js is as follow

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
const BaseHook = ({ ...props }) => {
    const [show, setshow] = useState(false);
       
//when hovered on activeInput -->'activeInput' is declared but its value is never read.
    const activeInput = (input) => {
        setshow(true);
   
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {props.children}
            {show ? <div>
               <p>Div is visible</p>
            </div> : null}
        </Fragment>
    );
};
BaseHook.propTypes = {
    activeInput:PropTypes.func,
};

export default BaseHook;
```

Now I am trying to use baseHook.js in another formHook.js where onFocus of input activeInput should get called.

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import BaseHook from "components/BaseHook";

const FormHook = ({ ...props }) => {

  return (
<BaseHook>
    <Fragment>  
      <input
        title= {"Input"}
        onFocus={() => activeInput(InputValue)}
        value={InputValue}
        className="required-field"
      />
    </Fragment>
<BaseHook> 
  );
     
};

export default FormHook;
```

activeInput function is not getting called from baseHook hence not able to setshow(true).
I am able to achieve this with react-class components using inheritance but is there way to call functions in composition in react-hooks?

Comment: Are you just trying to call a Child's function from the Parent?

Comment: Your naming is misleading, those are not hooks, you can just pass the callback via props or context API